# Multiple eigenvectors for a single eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Take for example the following matrix:

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2\\ 4 & 3\\\end{array}\right)$

This matrix has associated eigenvalues: 5 and -1.

I have seen two separate answers for the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue 5: $(1, 2)^T$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)^T$.

Are both of these eigenvectors a valid solution?

Thanks.

Comment: One solution has just been scaled by $2$. So yes, they are the same.

Comment: @Mattos I have read that you are supposed to take the $N(A-\lambda I)$ to find the eigenvector of an associated eigenvalue. When I do this method I get the second solution I listed. Do people scale their eigenvectors (to where they don't contain fractions) in order to simplify later calculations?

Comment: When you get your eigenvectors, they should be multiplied by some scalar $t$ i.e your eigenvector $\vec v$ should be of the form

$$\vec v = t \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

(note: I don't know what your actual eigenvector was, it could have been $t \cdot (1, 2)^{T}$ instead, I just assumed yours was scaled to make life easier).

Comment: Okay, thanks. So, any vector created from $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)^T$ multiplied by some scalar $t$ would be an eigenvector for this eigenvalue 5?

Comment: Yes. Try a few examples, such as $t = 10$ or $t = -5$ to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re making a fundamental error by talking about “the” eigenvector associated with an eigenvalue instead of “an” eigenvector. If $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then any non-zero scalar multiple of it is also an eigenvector: $A(k\mathbf v)=kA\mathbf v=k\lambda\mathbf v=\lambda(k\mathbf v)$. Thus there’s an entire subspace associated with each eigenvalue (and not necessarily one-dimensional, either).

The two vectors you’ve named are scalar multiples of each other, so they are both eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $5$.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, at least from what I've seen, it's common to refer to "the" eigenvector and assume that the listener is aware of the implicit equivalence between vectors that are a scale multiple of each other.

Comment: @WillR True enough, but that seems to be the source of the OP’s confusion in this case.